# Trying to display the total number of items in the shoppingcart object in FireBase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

The goal is to iterate through all the items in my FireBase Database, read the quantity of each item and then display the sum total on the front end. What I'm having issues with is using the async pipes to read an object value. Since using async as far as I understand it takes an arrays. I tried made the `cart$` an observable so that async can read it. But the compiler is telling me it but be set as an AngularFireObject, having it as such does not allow it to be read on the front end. Below is the relevant code.

bs-navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { AppUser } from '../models/app.user';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ShoppingCart } from '../models/shopping-cart';
import { AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  appUser: AppUser
  cart$: Observable<ShoppingCart>

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService) {
    auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser)
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout()
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.cart$ =  (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart())  
  }
}
```

On the line `this.cart$ =  (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart())` the following error appears: Type 'AngularFireObject' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)

shopping-cart.ts

```
import { ShoppingCartItem } from './shopping-cart-item';

export class ShoppingCart {
    items?: ShoppingCartItem[] = []

     get totalItemsCount() {
        let count = 0
        for (let productId in this.items) {
            count += this.items[productId].quantity
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

shopping-cart.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { take, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { removeSummaryDuplicates } from '@angular/compiler';
import { ShoppingCart } from './models/shopping-cart';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
    console.log('Create a cart item was called')
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts/').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    })
  }

  getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts' + cartId + '/items' + productId)
  }

  async getCart(): Promise<AngularFireObject<ShoppingCart>> {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId()
    console.log(this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId))
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId)
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId(): Promise<string> {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId')
    if (cartId) return cartId

    let result = await this.create()
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key)
    return result.key
  }

  async removeFromCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId()
    let item$ = this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + product.key)
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
      if (item.payload.exists()) item$.update({ product: product, quantity: item.payload.exportVal().quantity - 1 })
      else item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 })
    })
  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId()
    //Below we append the items to the shopping cart as a node below the original
    // shoppin-cart key
    let item$ = this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + product.key)
    item$.snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => {
      if (item.payload.exists()) item$.update({ product: product, quantity: item.payload.exportVal().quantity + 1 })
      else item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1 })
    })
  }
}
```

shopping-cart.component.html

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
<ng-container *ngIf="cart$ | async as cart">
    <p>
        You have {{ cart.totalItemsCount}} items in your shopping cart.
    </p>
</ng-container>
```

It is in the `{{ cart.totalItemsCount}}` that I am trying to display the total number of items in this particular shopping cart.
Below is attached [The firebase realtime database for the items and their associated quantities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpIqx.png)

Comment: Your `getCart()` function in your Service is returning a `Promise` and you are assigning it to an `Observable` type variable. If you want to make the result an observable (I don't see the point of it) you should probably create an observable from your Promise using the `from` operator from RxJs